# NTC Resistance considerations

Tags: resistance, temperature, thermistor

I'm sure this is a basic question but I am unable to find an answer anywhere online that explains it in a simple way.

I am researching NTC sensors and figuring out how to use them.

I want to know that the advantages or disadvantages of changing the NTC resistance will be ?

So far I have the assumption that a larger resistance ( 50K ) could meausre a greater range of temperatures ? ( than say a 10K )

But if both are 1% tolerance the larger resistance would not be as accurate because the range is bigger ?

Am I on the correct track here?

Also I take it that in my voltage divider circuit I should get a better tolerance resistor if I want the reading to be more accurate ?
( 1% instead of a 5% )

I am looking to measure temperatures of around 90 - 130 degrees C, with an accuracy of around 1 or 2 degrees, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the usable range will be the same regardless of the resistance at 25°C. The datasheet will tell you what range it is rated for and the accuracy at various temperatures (typically it will be most accurate at 25°C and less accurate the further you are from 25°C).

The dynamic range is an issue with thermistors. At high temperatures the resistance will be much lower than at 25°C so it may be more convenient (or require less expensive circuitry) to use a higher resistance thermistor, and if you have long wires to the thermistor their resistance may start to have an effect on the measurement.

Another factor is self-heating. You can calculate that from the power dissipated in the thermistor. Note that thermistor data sheets typically will show self-heating (and response times) in very favorable conditions such as water moving at 1m/s. In still air the performance will be much worse.

Typically NTC sensors change around 4% per degree C, so a 1% resistor is called for if you are looking for 1-2°C accuracy. Also an accurate thermistor- not only the tolerance at 25°C but the tolerance on \$\beta\$.

Comment: I am planning on using a 100K NTC having 1% tolerance and 1% beta accuracy. Would a 1Meg NTC be even better? Besides self-heating, why shouldn't I choose the highest resistance? And why does 10K seem to be the de-facto standard? Or should this be a bona fide question? Thanks, Spehro!

Comment: It has been a while since I worked on this project but I think you don't want to use a 1M Ohm because then your Voltage divider equation will skew to one side and you wont have much of a drop across your other resistor, I can't explain this perfectly but I am pretty sure that its important. For my project I used a 100K NTC and a 4.7K with 5V and it worked pretty well, hope this helps you.